# Each compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ with non zero measure has connected component with non-zero measure

Tags: real-analysis

EDIT: I am looking for:

A result that says compact subsets of $\mathbb{R} \supset K$ that have positive exterior measure $m_{\ast}(K) >0$ also have at least one connected subset $I$ of positive exterior measure, $m_{\ast}(I) >0$.

I have thought about it a bit and I think one can say that $I$ must be an interval since each connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.

Comment: Doesn't every subset have connected components, by definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) (like the Cantor set, but removing smaller open intervals) is compact, has positive measure, but contains no intervals of positive measure.

Comment: Good counter example. I wonder if there is  an extra condition (preferably weak) that I can place on my statement so that it becomes true?

Answer (score 0):

The Cantor set is compact and *totally disconnected*, that is, its only connected subsets are singleton points.

Comment: Good point. To be more specific, I am looking at subsets with positive exterior measure!

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you are specifically looking for.

Comment: Hi Kimchi, thanks, I have made the appropriate edit. I hope it is more clear